# grub 2.04 not reponding to usb keyboard

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, uefi

1. Since I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 my PC comes up with the grub boot screen where I'm supposed to be able to use the keyboard to either resume with the boot process or carry out some other process, BUT, the keyboard appears to be dead since grub does not respond. This is not a dual boot system.*emphasized text*
2. The only way to get the keyboard to work with grub is to disconnect the hard drives and switch the PC on. I then go into the BIOS and simply save and exit (making no changes) and then switch the PC off. I reconnect the hard drives and switch on the PC. When it gets to the grub screen and I hit enter, or arrow keys, grub responds immediately.
   The next time I boot up my PC, without disconnecting the hard drives, grub does not respond to the keyboard.
3. I also found that unless I disconnect the hard drives I cannot get to the BIOS settings using the usual "delete" or F2 keys which is something you are supposed to be able to do.
4. I've tried to change "auto" settings to enable and visa versa but none of these changes made any difference to the problem, which I didn't have with Ubuntu 18.04. I even disabled UEFI.
5. Does grub dynamically store BIOS info on the hard disk that is then used at boot time by the OS, in this case Ubuntu ? PLEASE HELP !

Comment: Is your USB keyboard plugged into a system/motherboard USB port, or a USB PCI card port? What brand keyboard?

Comment: The keyboard is plugged into the motherboard USB port. The keyboard is a Genius brand. It works very well once Ubuntu has booted up. I had no issues with it under Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is it a wireless keyboard... ie: uses a USB dongle?... or a strict USB wired keyboard? In your BIOS, is USB set to legacy? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: 1. It is USB wired keyoard   2.root@arno-pc:/home/arno# dmidecode -s bios-version
F10
3. Motherboard is GIGABYTE H77M-D3H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

GIGABYTE H77M-D3H

You have BIOS version F10.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F12, and it can be downloaded [here, for rev 1.0 motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-H77M-D3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios), or [here, for rev 1.1 motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-H77M-D3H-rev-11/support#support-dl-bios), or [here, for rev 1.2 motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H77M-D3H-rev-12/support#support-dl-bios).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web pages for your model #.

**Note**: If you have a different revision motherboard, it'll require a different download.

**Note**: There's actually a BIOS version F14, but it's a beta BIOS, and I wouldn't recommend that you install it.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: My motherboard is a rev 1.1 so I downloaded the appropriate BIOS version. The challenge is how to use the mb_bios_ga-h77m-d3h_f12.exe since I don't have a dual boot system, so no Windows. I do have a Windows XP Pro DVD that I can install on a separate disk if there is no shorter way of doing it. I assume the BIOS data is embedded in the exe file.

Comment: @ArnoVersfeld Some BIOS allow you to upgrade the BIOS from within the current BIOS. Check that out. Check the BIOS installation instructions. You might also try building a bootable FreeDOS USB stick to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help / advice!  I used the BIOS upgrade function to update the extracted data file. Grub now responds to the keyboard in the boot process.